# Different look in same size screen with different dpi

Tags: android

How to handle "dp" or "px" for different screen size so that my app supports multiple screen?

Comment: There's a plugin [Dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify) that might be useful to convert your dimens for different screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used one library to set same size to all screen.below to dependency add into project level gradle file.

```
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

and then after used in xml in any view control give size like below.to define size in working all screen.

```
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edevEtEventName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
            />
```

Comment: I used this and its working. I got this answer on some other question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make you application look same on different devices one can use drawable and dimensions folder structure, for drawable to look same for all different screen sizes and densities.

Apart from that application one can make different drawable folder for different screen size and for specific device as well.

Following is the list of folder names for both.

Drawable folders for different screen resolutions:

```
480x800 - drawable-hdpi - Sony Expedia
600x1024 - drawable-large-hdpi - Samsung tab2
720x1280 - drawable-xhdpi - Samsung s3
800x1280 - drawable-large-tvdpi - Nexus 7 tab
1080x1920 - drawable-xxhdpi - S4,Nexus5
1200x1920 - drawable-large-xhdpi - New nexus 7
1440X2560 - drawable-xxxhdpi - Nexus 6,Samsung S6edge
```

Dimen folder for different screen resolutions:

```
values-sw300dp
values-sw330dp
values-sw360dp
values-sw390dp
values-sw420dp
values-sw450dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw510dp
values-sw540dp
values-sw570dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw630dp
values-sw660dp
values-sw690dp
values-sw720dp
values-sw750dp
values-sw780dp
values-sw1080dp
values-v21
values-v24
values-w820dp
```